# How did Tigress reach the panda village?

Tags: plot-explanation, kung-fu-panda-3

In *Kung fu Panda 3*, the panda village was a secret place. But when Kai attacked and destroyed Jade Palace, Tigress reached the panda village and informed Po about what happaned to everyone. But if the panda village is a secret place, then how could Tigress reach it?